# Tally ERP on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4

I am trying to install Tally on a Raspberry Pi 4 4GB. I am currently using raspbian buster and twister OS. I installed tally in both the OSes using wine and box86. When I try to run it I get the following error:

> `0120:err:winediag:ODBC_LoadDriverManager failed to open library "libodbc.so": Cannot dlopen("libodbc.so"/0x43596b66, 101)`

After this error, nothing happens. The process doesn't even terminate until done manually.

Is there any way to make tally work properly in the ARM platform?

Comment: try this `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev libmyodbc`

Comment: i tried but its showing unable to locate

Comment: Try your luck installing
`libodbc1 - ODBC library for Unix`
`libodbcinstq4-1 - Qt-based ODBC configuration library`
`odbcinst1debian2 - Support library for accessing odbc ini files`

Comment: all files are already installed, main problem is its failed to open those libraries,its not saying that file not found

Comment: by executing this command "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libodbc.so" before running i can over come that error now am getting new issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to get ARM based installer. Ask Tally group to convert their code to run on ARM architecture or linux.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As Tally ERP seems to be Windows only (according to their website needs at least Windows 7 - which in return needs powerful x86 hardware) this cannot be emulated on a much weaker ARM system. As `@AnandSingh` correctly said above, ask Tally if they can compile their software so that it can run on Raspberry Pi. Which heavily depends how they have developed their software.